# Op-amp DC multiplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog

Is there a circuit (that only uses an op-amp and resistors) that performs multiplication between two DC input signals v1 and v2? Similar to the [Summing Amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier) but with multiplication.

Comment: I'm not sure you can, since dynamic multiplication is nonlinear. Analog Devices app note [MT-079](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-079.pdf) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, that PDF touch on the subject, using Log Amps to make multipliers. Interesting approach, but not what I'm looking for right now because log amps uses diodes and transistors.

Comment: @user246185 opamps use diodes and transistors too, so why does it matter that log amps do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: No there is no circuit that just uses op-amps and resistors that can multiply two voltages.

You can multiply one voltage times a resistor value. You can do things with log amplifiers and antilog amplifiers, you can do things with PWM, but all of those things (except the resistor value one) involve other (nonlinear) elements.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, not perfect.  The first op-amp (A) receiving the input voltage X on the (+) input, with some positive offset at the (+) to raise the output offset voltage, some gain, feeding a small mosfet or bipolar, drain/collector to point C, source/emitter to ground.  A second op-amp (B) receiving the second voltage Y on (+) input, it has some gain (20x or more) by feedback via resistors J (output) and K (- input).  K resistor should go to ground, but it does not, it is point C, so the bipolar/mosfet drains more or less current from K, based on the X voltage.  This is basically a B gain controlled by voltage X. This is a multiplication, non linear, and don't expect the output of B go to zero when X or Y is zero, it can be done but...  For some non linear or non precision output, it works.   The correct way is really using a multiplication chip as AD633 or using op-amps with diodes for log/anti-log, but those will imply problems with temperature.

Comment: A circuit diagram is always better than words.

Comment: Also uses mosfets and/or bipolar transistors, which OP didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do it if you build a [voltage controlled amplifier](https://amplifiercircuit.net/voltage-controlled-variable-gain-amplifier.html) where gain is controlled by an input voltage